# Error: query body must end with a select clause or a group clause

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm trying to convert this query from MS-SQL to entity

this is the original query:

```
SELECT    sys_id

FROM      table1

          inner join table2 on table1.client_id = table2.client_id 
          and table1.local_seq = table2.local_seq 

          WHERE table1.client_id = @ClientID
```

And this is the converted code to Entity

```
var dbListingSysId = (from type in db.table1
                                      join borrower in db.table2 on new { type.client_id, type.local_seq } equals new { borrower.client_id, borrower.local_seq }
                                      where type.client_id == clientId
                                      select new {type.listingid }).ToList();
```

But i get error:

> A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause

Comment: You are missing the equivalent of `and borrower_sys_id = @siBorrowerSysId` in the Linq query. Maybe it is confused about the join that you never use.

Comment: @HenkHolterman i dont think that entity knows what im thinking of and warning me about it , assume that its just client_sys_id = siClientSysId